# Cointegration between linear combinations sets of time series

Tags: integration

A linear combination of two time series $(X_1, X_2, ..., X_k)$ is a new time series $Y$ constructed as follows for any set of real numbers $b_1...b_k$.

$$Y = b_1X_1 + b_2X_2 + \dots + b_kX_k$$

### Formal Definition of Cointegration:

For some set of time series ($X_1, X_2, ..., X_k)$, if all series are $I(1)$, and some linear combination of them is $I(0)$, we say the set of time series is cointegrated.

### Example:

$X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$ are all $I(1)$, and $2X_1 + X_2 + 0X_3 = 2X_1 + X_2$ is $I(0)$. In this case the time series are cointegrated.

Linear Combinations X and Y are assumed to be cointegrated.

X = $a_1 b_1, a_2 b_2,\dots ,a_n b_n$
Y = $b_1 c_1, b_2 c_2, \dots ,b_n c_n$
Z = $a_1 c_1, a_2 c_2, \dots ,a_n c_n$

If X and Y are both cointegrated linear combinations, can it be assumed that Z is also a cointegrated linear combination?

Comment: This is really unclear.  What does co-integrated mean?

Comment: Definition: If there exists a stationary linear combination of nonstationary random variables, the variables combined are said to be cointegrated.

Comment: Please give all the definitions in your question. Also give your ideas so far.

Comment: Updated the question more clearly. Because X and Y are both cointegrated linear combinations, I don't see a reason why Z wouldn't be considered cointegrated as well.